# What can I use to replace PHP sessions sharing via memcache

Tags: php, security, session, memcached, centralized

I am looking for sharing my PHP sessions so the easiest solution is to use memcache. But I need something more secure, because memcache doesn't have failover, clusterisation, persistence …

I thought about Redis, but it doesn't have a PHP module that handle it, so no session_handler

So basically, I need something to manage the sessions in a centralized way and relatively secure. And my research on the internet aren't very fructuous.

Comment: Who told you that PHP can't use Redis as session storage? Why would you need a "module"? You just specify the session handler to be Redis in the same way you would with Memcache. I've been using it for some time, so your statement that it PHP and Redis don't play together is simply false.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that. And about security, do you have just a port or can you authenticate with the session handler ?

Comment: Right, personally I don't use any sort of authentication at the moment nor have I checked whether it's doable, so you might want to refere to Redis' documentation. However, it's also not quite true that you can't authenticate with Memcache, [refer to this link for more info](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/SASLAuthProtocol).

Comment: https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis#php-session-handler

Comment: @N.B. You should post your comment as an answer so we can vote them up and Simon can accept them if they work :)

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady You should post your comment as an answer so we can vote them up and Simon can accept them if they work :)

Comment: @culix I just didn't really want to post a URL kind of answer, but I guess i could do that.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought about Redis, but it doesn't have a PHP module that handle it, so no session_handler

Check [phpredis](https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis), it provides [a session handler](https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis#php-session-handler) for redis, and as for security I don't think you need to configure some sort of authentication, you can somehow make the server only accept the IP's of the application servers.